# Spring Mockmvc ignores unknown fields

Tags: mockito, spring-test-mvc

The API method has already been validated with @Valid annotation. When I test this method using postman, and post an unknown field, it works, and rejects the request. However, when I test this using mockMvc, mockMvc ignores unknown fields. Any idea how I can enforce mockMvc to consider the validation in the API method.

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/path", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> notification(@Valid @RequestBody RequestClass requestPayload) {

}
```

Test method

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/path" )
                
                .content("{\"fakeField\":\"fake\",\"userId\":\"clientId\"")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        String responseMessage = "Error message";

        this.mockMvc =
                standaloneSetup(myController)
                .build();

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(builder)
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString(responseMessage)));
```

Comment: The question is why you have `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` set to `true` in production code, and to `false` it tests. This boils down to question: how you configured your ObjectMapper?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for unknown fields and returning a 400 (`BAD_RQUEST`) is a deserialization feature of Jackson (the `ObjectMapper`). It's not handled by Java's Bean Validation.

With your custom `MockMvc` standalone setup you opt-out of the default Spring Boot auto-configuration which would configure the `ObjectMapper` according to your configured features.

I'd recommend using `@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)` [for your controller tests](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/) and then inject the auto-configured `MockMvc`:

```
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class) // auto-configures everything in the background for your, including the ObjectMapper
class YourControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;


}
```